# Does 1,3-butadiene in bromine/water do addition twice?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Considering 1,3-butadiene (below) added to bromine water (considering it as $\ce{Br2(aq)}$):
[image]

I've seen online that the products are 1,2-dibromobutene and 1,4
[image]

but what I don't understand is why wouldn't the other double bond undergo substitution again? They're on a carbon chain like normal so shouldn't they react with the bromine water too? Is something stopping it?

Comment: Given enough time and Br2, it would.

Comment: Please don't use MathJax in titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If reaction is carried out in 1:1 ratio of Br2 and 1,3 Butadiene, then the above two products will be formed. If more Br2 is taken, then surely 4 positions will be brominated.

Comment: Why answer a question that has already been answered by @Ivan Neretin in a comment?

Comment: @user55119 because a comment is not an answer.